# Repeated regular expression with fall through

Tags: python, regex

Let's say you have this string:  'catdogfoxdogdogfoxcat'

I can easily split this using the following regex:
`re.compile('(dog)|(cat)|(fox)').findall(the_string)`

In python, you get this out as a result:

```
[('', 'cat', ''),
 ('dog', '', ''),
 ('', '', 'fox'),
 ('dog', '', ''),
 ('dog', '', ''),
 ('', '', 'fox'),
 ('', 'cat', '')]
```

Which is perfect.

Let's now change that string to: 'catdogaaadogdogbbbcat'

I can't figure out how to do this if the third regex item is arbitrary (aaa/bbb/whatever). I.e. I want something like this:  `re.compile('(dog)|(cat)|(.*?)').findall(the_string)`

Currently I get the following result, which doesn't make sense...

```
[('', 'cat', ''),
 ('dog', '', ''),
 ('', '', ''),
 ('', '', ''),
 ('', '', ''),
 ('dog', '', ''),
 ('dog', '', ''),
 ('', '', ''),
 ('', '', ''),
 ('', '', ''),
 ('', 'cat', ''),
 ('', '', '')]
```

What is going wrong here? How do I fix my regular expression?

I rather expect a result like this:

```
[('', 'cat', ''),
 ('dog', '', ''),
 ('', '', 'aaa'),
 ('dog', '', ''),
 ('dog', '', ''),
 ('', '', 'bbb'),
 ('', 'cat', '')]
```

Comment: I'd rather [use something like this - `filter(None, re.split(r"(dog|cat)", "catdogfoxdogdogfoxcat"))`](http://ideone.com/kElQOY).

Comment: `.*` will match an empty sequence. It's definitely not what you want. What are the requirements on the arbitrary thing you want to match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without extra conditions the `.*?` would match any empty string. Request it to be followed by `dog`, `cat`, or end of text:

```
(dog)|(cat)|(.*?)(?=dog|cat|$)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/UPwom6/1

Comment: Yay!  PS: Is the $ strictly necessary?

Comment: This doesnt match the OP's desired output. That is, this also gives an empty matched group! `[('', 'cat', ''), ('dog', '', ''), ('', '', 'aaa'), ('dog', '', ''), ('dog', '', ''), ('', '', 'bbb'), ('', 'cat', ''), ('', '', '')]`

Comment: Ok. Seems $ is required after all if the string does not contain *any* cat/dog.

Comment: that is why the `('', '', '')` is also present in the result!

Answer (score 1):

The regex will start at position 0 of *the_string*, or more specifically, `the_string[0]` and will begin searching for a match using the alternations you provided: first `dog` and, if that's not found, `cat`, and finally `.*?` (which is "0 items, unless I need to match more").

If the regex fails to find `dog` OR `cat` OR `.*?`, then at that point, it will step one character further into the string: `the_string[1]` and try again at that new point.

The `.*?` says to match "zero or more characters, as few times as possible" which is the same as saying "match a zero-length string at position `the_string[0]`", which it will always do: the result is always "empty".

The tricky way to do this is to say: `dog` or `cat` or "all text UNTIL `dog` or `cat`":

```
(dog)|(cat)|((?:(?!dog|cat).)*)
```

The result [is this](https://regex101.com/r/rQnBPH/1/).

It's not very clean, and it's a bit slow, so you may want to try for a different approach here: remove all `dog` and `cat` within the text, and whatever is left over is the remaining text that you want.

Answer (score 0):

the third string is arbitrary and may be or may not be present!
That is

```
the_string='catdogaaadogdogbbbcat'
re.compile('(dog)|(cat)|(\w{3}?)').findall(the_string)
[('', 'cat', ''), ('dog', '', ''), ('', '', 'aaa'), ('dog', '', ''), ('dog', '', ''), ('', '', 'bbb'), ('', 'cat', '')]
```

Hope it helps!